# how to view image on canvas from multiple image

Tags: html5-canvas

this is my code:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
    <head>

    <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="940" height="600" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">
    Your browser does not support the canvas element.
    </canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ImageLoad()
        {
            var ctx = document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext('2d');

            var img = new Image();   // Create new img element  
            img.onload = function(){  
              // execute drawImage statements here  This is essential as it waits till image is loaded before drawing it.
                ctx.drawImage(img , 0, 0);

            };  
            img.src = $('img[alt="example"]').attr('src'); // Set source path 

        }
    </script>
    <!--<img src="basicCycle.jpg"/>-->
    <table border="1px">
    <tr>
    <td><a href="javascript:ImageLoad()"><img src="cycle6.jpg" alt="example" height="120" width="120"></a></td>
    <td><a href="javascript:ImageLoad()"><img src="cycle1.jpg" alt="example" height="120" width="120"></a></td>
    <td><a href="javascript:ImageLoad()"><img src="cycle2.jpg" alt="example" height="120" width="120"></a></td>
    <td><a href="javascript:ImageLoad()"><img src="cycle3.jpg" alt="example" height="120" width="120"></a></td>
    <td><a href="javascript:ImageLoad()"><img src="cycle4.jpg" alt="example" height="120" width="120"></a></td>
    <td><a href="javascript:ImageLoad()"><img src="cycle5.jpg" alt="example" height="120" width="120"></a></td>
    <td><a href="javascript:ImageLoad()"><img src="cycle6.jpg" alt="example" height="120" width="120"></a></td>
    <td><a href="javascript:ImageLoad()"><img src="cycle1.jpg" alt="example" height="120" width="120"></a></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

now i want to load cycle1 in canvas when i click to cycle1 image.and load cycle2 when i click to cycle2 image.
the problem is my code always load first td image.whatever i clicked.

Comment: But what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are always setting the src to that of the image whose alt is "example" and all the images have that alt, so you are always getting the first one.

Instead of:

```
img.src = $('img[alt="example"]').attr('src'); // Set source path
```

Do this:

```
img.src = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
```

"this" refers to the link that was clicked, but you need to replace the href values with "#":

```
<td><a href="#"><img src="cycle1.jpg" alt="example" height="120" width="120"></a></td>
```

And put this right before the closing `<script>` tag:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a').click(ImageLoad);
});
```

You should also put:

```
return false;
```

as the last line inside ImageLoad(). This will keep the page from jumping to the top, if it has been scrolled.